# How to use an IN operator in a dynamic query

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, dynamicquery

I would like to use the in operator in a dynamic query . At the moment I need someone to point in in the right direction as to how to structure the apostrophes for separating values so that they don't interfere with the apostrophes for the dynamic query structure. This is a section of the query that is giving problems so what I need to know is how where to place the separator so that all of values can be included in dynamic query format as opposed to the regular query format that I have right now

```
WHERE ai.ImNumber != me.Company 
    AND me.ID IN ('value1','value2','value2','value3','value4','value5')'
```

My Query is

```
SET @SQLString = 'select me.EventID , ai.AggregateInfo, '''+@DateBegin+''' AS DateBegin, '''+@EDateEnd+''' AS DateEnd 
FROM tbl_MajorEarners me 
INNER JOIN tbl_currentearners e ON e.EventID = me.EventID 
INNER JOIN tbl_AggregateInfo ai ON ai.AggregateID = cs.ItemID 
WHERE ai.ImNumber != me.CompanyNUmber 
AND me.ID IN ('value1','value2','value2','value3','value4','value5')'
```

Comment: is this for mysql or sql-server?

Comment: add more details about your question? will you have max 5 dynamic values? your question is not clear

Comment: I am using sqlserver 2008 and this is my dynamic query  
 'SET @SQLString = 'select me.EventID , ai.AggregateInfo, 
 '''+@DateBegin+''' AS DateBegin, '''+@EDateEnd+''' AS DateEnd
 FROM  tbl_MajorEarners me 
 INNER JOIN tbl_currentearners e 
 ON e.EventID = me.EventID  
 INNER JOIN tbl_AggregateInfo ai ON
 ai.AggregateID = cs.ItemID

        WHERE ai.ImNumber != me.CompanyNUmber 
        AND me.ID IN ('value1','value2','value2','value3','value4','value5')''

Comment: My apologies I figured that I should place  a  plus sign in front of each value e.g (+value+ , +value+ , +value+)

Comment: @anchor Don't put additional info into comments. You can edit the question.

Comment: if you have 5 values as defined in your query, why do you need dynamic sql?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
SET @SQLString = 'select me.EventID , ai.AggregateInfo, ''@DateBegin'' AS DateBegin, ''@EDateEnd'' AS DateEnd 
FROM tbl_MajorEarners me 
INNER JOIN tbl_currentearners e ON e.EventID = me.EventID 
INNER JOIN tbl_AggregateInfo ai ON ai.AggregateID = cs.ItemID 
WHERE ai.ImNumber != me.CompanyNUmber 
AND me.ID IN (''value1'',''value2'',''value2'',''value3'',''value4'',''value5'')'
```

which sets `@SqlString` to

```
select me.EventID , ai.AggregateInfo, '@DateBegin' AS DateBegin, '@EDateEnd' AS DateEnd 
FROM tbl_MajorEarners me 
INNER JOIN tbl_currentearners e ON e.EventID = me.EventID 
INNER JOIN tbl_AggregateInfo ai ON ai.AggregateID = cs.ItemID 
WHERE ai.ImNumber != me.CompanyNUmber 
AND me.ID IN ('value1','value2','value2','value3','value4','value5')
```